# How do I use hbsfy to compile templates to js?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, gulp

I'm using hbsfy in my project and I'd like the result of a template when `require()`'d to be returned as a raw javascript. I'm coming from a grunt background where grunt-contrib-handlebars did this for me. However, I like how hbsfy lets me `require()` the file and just use it. So, is there a way to have my cake and eat it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify transform options:

```
        browserify: {
        options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
                transform: 'hbsfy'
            }
        },
        main: {
            src: '**.js',
            dest: '**.js'
        }
```